# PHP - How to count a generators yields

Tags: php, generator, yield

Using PHP >= 5.5 if we have a method that yielded values, what would be the best method in counting these values?

What I was expecting was to be able to convert a Generator to an array and count that, however it would return an empty array. Count() also does not work as the Generator is reported as empty despite not being empty.

I'm baffled with this. If you don't need to count a generators yields then it's a nice feature otherwise I don't see much of a point for it. There is a way to detect if a generator is empty, this is by using the key() method and if it returns NULL then there are either no yields or the generator has already been iterated through which would mean the current pointer is null.

Comment: At the moment of posting this, I had only tried count() which was mentioned in the post and that did not work. I am also on topic as it's a specific programming problem that I had. As for providing a code example, I suppose I could of done to show my current usage but I was expecting those who clicked on this post would know the usage of yields in PHP anyway. With that covered, I am unaware that I have broken any rules but if I have done so then I am truly sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should understand, that [generator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) isn't data structure - it's an instance of [`Generator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.generator.php) class and, actually, it's special sort of `Iterator`. Thus, you can't count its items directly (to be precise - that's because `Generator` class implements only [`Iterator`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface, and not [`Countable`](https://www.php.net/Countable) interface. To be honest, I can't imagine how can it implement that)

To count values with native generator you'll have to iterate through it. But that can not be done in common sense - because in most cases it's **you** who'll decide how many items will be yielded. Famous `xrange()` sample from manual:

```
function xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if ($start < $limit) {
        if ($step <= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be +ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i <= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    } else {
        if ($step >= 0) {
            throw new LogicException('Step must be -ve');
        }

        for ($i = $start; $i >= $limit; $i += $step) {
            yield $i;
        }
    }
}
```

-as you can see, it's **you** who must define borders. And final count will depend from that. Iterating through generator will have sense only with static-borders defined generator (i.e. when count of items is always static - for example, defined inside generator strictly). In any other case you'll get parameter-dependent result. For `xrange()`:

```
function getCount(Generator $functor)
{
   $count = 0;
   foreach($functor as $value)
   {
      $count++;
   }
   return $count;
}
```

-and usage:

```
var_dump(getCount(xrange(1, 100, 10)));//10
var_dump(getCount(xrange(1, 100, 1)));//100
```

-as you can see, "count" will change. Even worse, generator hasn't to be finite. It may yield infinite set of values (and borders are defined in external loop, for example) - and this is one more reason which makes "counting" near senseless.

Comment: I understand. In my situation I was actually yielding objects in a loop of rows from the database which means whilst there is one "yield" statement, it's being repeated multiple times. The only ways I could come up with was to clone the generator and iterate on that (allowing the original generator to still be iterated through for its data) or counting the rows separately. So based on what you said, I must not be using it in the best practise?

Comment: In SQL there's `COUNT` grouping function. Use that instead

Comment: I suppose that counting wouldn't be useful if the generator is infinite, however in a case where one would infinitely use the same generator - at which point would it stop allowing you to use the values stored in the generator? It would eventually have to stop otherwise it's just pointlessly yielding values, right? By counting the rows, I do mean by using COUNT but it would have to be a separate query. One to get the count of rows and one to get the data. Then yield both the count the data meaning the first value in the generator would be the row count. Would that be how you'd do such a thing?

Comment: The thing is - you'll have to _iterate_ to get count. That doesn't sound as a good idea, especially if there are many elements in result set. Too big overhead for too small feature. I'm still recommending use SQL's `COUNT()` because it's intended to do that.

Comment: you can alwyays use `iterator_to_array`, but it looses interest, since you'll have to iterator over all the values to find it out.

Answer (score 22):

If you have to do it, following as a on-liner of native functions:

```
count(iterator_to_array($generator, false));
```

However, take care: After this your `$generator` is executed and *consumed*. So if you would put that same `$generator` into a `foreach` in a following line, it would loop 0 times.

Generators are by design highly dynamic (in contrast to fixed data structures like arrays), thats why they don't offer `->count()` or `->rewind()`.

Comment: Hopefully the use of native functions makes this method more efficient than the one described by @Alma Do. Can it be used to sort, rather than count, the array?

Answer (score 6):

Actually, it depends in which case you are :

**Case 1** : I can't count before iterating and I care about values

```
// The plain old solution
$count = 0;
foreach($traversable as $value) {
    // Do something with $value, then…
    ++$count;
}
```

**Case 2** : I can't count before iterating but I don't care about values

```
// let's iterator_count() do it for me
$count = iterator_count($traversable);
```

**Case 3** : I can count before iterating but I don't care about values

I try not to use generators.

For example (with SQL backends) :

```
SELECT count(1) FROM mytable; // then return result
```

is better than

```
SELECT * FROM mytable; // then counting results
```

Other example (with xrange from Alma Do) :

```
// More efficient than counting by iterating
function count_xrange($start, $limit, $step = 1) {
    if (0 === $step) throw new LogicException("Step can't be 0");
    return (int)(abs($limit-$start) / $step) + 1;
}
```

**Case 4** : I can count before iterating and I care about values

I can use a generator AND a count function

```
$args = [0,17,2];

$count = count_xrange(...$args);
$traversable = xrange(...$args);
```

**Case 5** : Case 4, and **I want all in one object**

I can "decorate" an Iterator to make a Countable Iterator

```
function buildCountableIterator(...$args) {

    $count = count_xrange(...$args);
    $traversable = xrange(...$args);

    return new class($count, $traversable) extends \IteratorIterator implements \Countable {
        private $count;
        public function __construct($count, $traversable) {
            parent::__construct($traversable);
            $this->count = $count;
        }
        public function count() {
            return $this->count;
        }
    }
}

$countableIterator = buildCountableIterator(1, 24, 3);

// I can do this because $countableIterator is countable
$count = count($countableIterator); 

// And I can do that because $countableIterator is also an Iterator
foreach($countableIterator as $item) {
    // do something
}
```

Sources :

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-count.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.iteratoriterator.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.anonymous.php

Answer (score 2):

While you can't use `count()` you can use a reference to set the count to make it accessible to the outside world.

```
function generate(&$count = 0) {
    // we have 4 things
    $count = 4;
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        yield $i;
    }
}

$foo = generate($count);
echo $count; // 4
foreach ($foo as $i) {
     echo $i;
}
```

Downside to this is it won't tell you how many remain but how many it started with.

Comment: Generator code is not executed until you try to read first item. This means your `$count` will be always `0`. To get the count out of the generator you must first start it: `$foo = generate($count); $foo->current(); echo $count;  /* now $count is 4 */`